# How to drawImage() and replace old contents with new?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

In JS, I have some performance-critical code that essentially looks like this:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
context.drawImage(otherImage);
```

I profile my code with Chrome and I find that the bottleneck is... `clearRect`.

Wait, what?

This is really stupid. I shouldn't even *need* to `clearRect`! I'm currently touching every pixel of `context` twice (once for clearRect, once for drawImage), which is a total waste. In theory, I should only need to do it once, to directly copy each pixel from `otherImage` to `context`.

How can I say something like "please, screw alpha blending and whatever, just **replace the contents of context with whatever is in `otherImage`**!"

Comment: Even if `gCO = copy` is a good solution, I can't believe clearRect is the bottleneck, what's the size of your canvas ? Also, with only one parameter, drawImage should throw an error.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah, you're right; in recent tests it's been something like drawImage 2x for clearRect x. Nevertheless, nothing else even comes close on the perf chart. (and yeah, the code up there is just pseudocode since it's not really the point of the question... the real render loop is quite a bit more complex)

Comment: Well you are talking about a really odd issue (clearRect being slower than anything else...), so showing real code might improve the question. But now I see that this part of the question was actually noise (not directly related to the request). Also, note that even with copy, there is antialiasing which is performed, so there is always a bit of alpha blending (which can be disabled **only** for images)

Comment: As I clarified, it's something like 33% clearRect drawImage 66%. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ensure that no blending is done by calling `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';` (default), which performs only alpha blending or `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';` which literally just copies the image on top of the existing content ([see the examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation))

Comment: I don't quite understand. If `source-over` is the default, then why is it that when I draw two images on top of each other with `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`, the alphas are combined rather than just getting another image with `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` (which is what I want!)?

Comment: `source-over` actually uses the alpha channels and doesn't do any other blending: as you can see in the example, the alpha is preserved and the background image shows through. On the other hand, `copy` literally just copies input to output (I have indicated that in the answer now, thanks for correcting).

Comment: Unfortunately neither `source-over` nor `copy` do what I want. `copy` completely removes the old image, and `source-over` does alpha blending. I'd ideally like a compositing operation that takes pixels from the new image if they aren't fully transparent, and otherwise takes pixels from the old image - no alpha blending whatsoever.

Comment: @thedayturns, to avoid only semi-alpha, you'd have to iterate through the whole image data, to remove the non 255 alpha pixels. No compositing do allow to take only full opaque pixels.

Comment: Ah, I see I wasn't super clear in my original question. I'll just mark this as correct since it answers what I had asked.